# Change Fragment in ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android

I have SettingsActivity like in [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

It works properly, but when SettingsActivity extends from ActionBarActivity (subclass of Activity) then I got blank screen. Can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better not extend the main activity to `ActionBarActivity`, because `ActionBarActivity` uses *campcatv7* and it is really, believe me, not working properly.

You just extend `Activity` and later in your main activity declare whatever you wish and any kind of settings or animations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. ActionBarActivity is only needed for API 7-10. Its from the Appcompat support library and uses the method getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). Also there is no equivalent of PreferenceFragment in the support library. There are various workarounds.

One other thing to mention - if you choose to use a fragment (see code below) it may not appear. I think there's a bug somewhere. It does appear if added in its own handler thread:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check if this activity was created before
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
    // Create a fragment
        new Handler().post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                StatusFragment fragment = new StatusFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment,
                fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit(); 
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Activity class as an interface and then implement it.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Activity {


}
```

Comment: You can't implement a class and ActionBarActivity inherits from Activity. So many things wrong with this.